# Probability with n characters

Tags: probability

This is taken from a stochastic processes text.

A printing machine capable of printing any of n characters $a_1, ... , a_n$ is operated by electrical impulses, each character, in theory, being produced by a different impulse. Suppose the machine has probability $p$ of producing the character corresponding to the impulse received, independent of past behavior. If it prints the wrong character, the probabilities that any of the $(n-1)$ other characters will appear are equal.

The question is:  Suppose that one of the $n$ impulses is chosen at random and fed into the machine twice, and the character $a_i$ is printed both times. What is the probability that the impulse chosen is the one designed to produce $a_i$?

I thought that the answer can be found by supposing two characters are $a_i$ with probability $p$ and the remaining $(n-2)$ characters are not each with probability $(1-p)$.

I think this would be $${n\choose 2} p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$$

The actual answer is $$p^2[p^2 + \frac{(1-p)^2}{n-1}]^{-1}$$

Looking at this, it seems it might be a conditional probability, but I do not understand what A and B would be in $P(A|B)$.

I also thought that you need to consider at least two characters = $a_i$ as opposed to exactly two, but I do not see how this would lead to the actual answer.

I think there is something about the problem and the question that I do not understand. Please clarify, and please show or give hints as to obtain the actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event that impulse $i$ is chosen and $B$ the event that the first and the second printed letter is $a_i$.

Use Bayes theorem to obtain the desired probability.
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A)P(A)+ P(B|notA)P(notA)}
$$

Now, $P(A) = 1/n, P(B|A) = p^2, P(B|notA)=((1-p)/(n-1))^2, P(notA)=(n-1)/n.$

Substituting in the formula, the result is $p^2/(p^2+(1-p)^2/(n-1)).$

Note that $(1-p)/(n-1)$ is the probability that letter $a_i$ is printed given that impulse other than $i$ is selected.

Comment: In this case is it difficult to find P(A|B) directly using P(AB)/B?  Also, I'm unclear on P(B|not A). It seems that P(B intersect not A) would be (1-p)^2 so the result would be (1-p)^2n/(n-1).

Comment: Try thinking in terms of conditional probabilities as specified in  the Bayes formula. These conditionals are simpler to compute as shown above. $P(B|notA)  = (1-p)^2/(n-1)^2$ is the probability that letter $a_i$ is printed twice given that impulse other than  is selected.

Comment: That makes sense intuitively, but I was thinking of $P(B|not A) = P(B not A)/P(not A) = (1-p)^2/((n-1)/n)) = (1-p)^2n/(n-1)$. Why does this approach differ by an extra n?

Comment: Event $(B|notA)$ consists of two independent events, $(B_1|not A) =$  "$a_i$ is the first letter printed given that impulse $i$ is not selected" and $(B_2|not A)=$  "$a_i$ is the second letter printed given that impulse $i$ is not selected". $Pr(B|not A)=Pr(B_1| not A)Pr(B_2 |not A)$, where $Pr(B_1| not A)=Pr(B_2| not A)= (1-p)/(n-1)$.

Comment: Is there any difference in this case between $P(B|not A)$ and $P(B \cap not A)$?

Comment: $P(B \cap not A) = P(B, not A) = P(B|not A)P(not A)$. Thus the two are not equal.